# foreach function doesnt shows my database values properly

Tags: php

here is my code for each it dosent shows all db values except last one;

```
<?php
        foreach($result as $query2)

                    echo '<tr>'; 
        echo "<td>" . $query2['firstname']. "</td>";
        echo"<td>".$query2['username']."</td>";
        echo"<td>".$query2['firstname']."</td>";
        echo"<td>".$query2['lastname']."</td>";
        echo"<td>".$query2['gender']."</td>";
        echo"<td>".$query2['email']."</td>";
        echo"<td>".$query2['mobile']."</td>";
        echo"<td>".$query2['address']."</td>";
        echo "<td><a href='http://localhost/service/change.php?edit_id=".$query2['uid']."'>Edit</a></td>";
        //echo"<td><a href="http://localhost/service/change.php?edit_id= ".$query2['uid']."">Edit</a>
        //<a href="http://localhost/service/delete.php?delet_id=<?php echo $query2['uid']?X</a></td>
                    echo "<td><a href='http://localhost/service/delete.php?delet_id=".$query2['uid']."'>x</a></td>";
          echo '</tr>'; 


        ?>
```

Comment: please show us your code where you get your values! A query is there to make a request and the result if often another variable. We need to see how you make this query and if and where you store your result

Comment: `print_r($result)` and post its value

Comment: That's because `$result` has only last value which you got from database. Show us database code to rectify the issue.

Comment: this is wrong. You can not know what result is because there is no code which shows what is inside result!

Comment: And why do you not use `{ ... }` ?

Comment: thanks. i did not use the { }  now i have done that it runs thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use key- value reference for that....

```
foreach($result as $key=>$value)
{
  echo "<td>" . $value['firstname']. "</td>"; 
  echo "<td>" . $value['lastname']. "</td>";
}
```